# How Can I Change Screen Resolution ( Tried xrandr method )

Tags: resolution

After Install OS , Mine Screen Resolution was struck on DEFAULT resolution

Comment: Which video card do you have? Is your system up to date?

Comment: I Dont have Graphic Card , My Lcd Dell 240wfp its has 1920 *1200 60htrz